# Confused on using JSON Object for this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript I want to have a JSON or array that will store `id` & `ip` data pairs, such that if I want the `ip` of a particular `id=123`, I can easily get it, ie by using `data[123]` or `data['123']['ip']`.

I tried this but cant seem to select the `ip` based on `id`:

```
var connected_clients = {
    "clients": [{id: "12345", ip: "123.123.123.123"}]
};
```

Also tried using this below, but I cant seem to add new id/ip pairs to it...

```
var connected_clients = {
    "12345": {
        id: "12345",
        ip: "123.123.123.123"
    }
};
```

How should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(First up, you don't have "a JSON", you have an object. JSON is a string representation of data - or you could think of it as an object serialised to string form. Anyway...)

If you want to be able to look up the details for a known id, your second structure will work fine.

With more clients it would look like this:

```
var connected_clients = {
    "12345": {
        id: "12345",
        ip: "123.123.123.123"
    },
    "12346": {
        id: "12346",
        ip: "123.234.345.456"
    },
    "12347": {
        id: "12347",
        ip: "555.444.333.222"
    }
};
```

And you'd get the ip of client "12346" like this:

```
connected_clients["12346"]["ip"]
// OR
connected_clients["12346"].ip
// OR if the id was in a variable
var currentId = "12346";
connected_clients[currentId]["ip"]
```

If you want to add a client:

```
connected_clients[newId] = { id: newId, ip : someIp };
```

If you want to check if a particular id already exists:

```
if (connected_clients.hasOwnProperty(someId)) {
   // do something
}
// OR use 'in' since your object doesn't really have a prototype chain to worry about
if (someId in connected_clients) {
   // do something
}
```

To iterate through all the clients:

```
for (var key in connected_clients) {
   console.log(key + " - ip is " + connected_clients[key]["ip"]);
}
```

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 1):

The second should work fine for in your case. New Elements would be added like follow (assuming (`id` and `ip` are given as variables):

```
 connected_clients[ id ] = { 'id': id, 'ip': ip };
```

This does *not* check, whether there is already an entry under that id. You would have to check for it separately, i presume.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
 var connected_clients = {
   "clients": [{"id": "12345", "ip": "123.123.123.123"}]
  };
```

[json in javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like

var test = {
    "12345": "123.123.123.123"
};

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery map() utility function to extract the Single dimensional array to an associative array. Refer the link below.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score -1):

```
var connected_clients = {
    "12345":{"id":"12345","ip":"123.123.123.123"},
    "45673":{"id":"45673","ip":"234.234.234.234"},
    "21346":{"id":"21346","ip":"213.213.213.213"}};
```

Now:

```
client_ip = connected_clients["12345"]["ip"];
```

Comment: You need to use curly brackets `{}` in your object literal.

Comment: It's an array literal. I was almost certain I could use [] for arrays.

Comment: You are right that you would use `[]` for an array literal, but what you have is not an array. Arrays don't use the `:` syntax because they don't have property names (they have implied numeric indexes).

Comment: Oops. Wait, JS doesn't have associative arrays? What the hell is going on..

What does this syntax: myArray["someIndex"] actually mean then?

Comment: JavaScript's version of an associative array is an "object". You get or set individual properties of an existing object using square brackets like an array, so `myObj["someProperty"]` will give you the `someProperty` property of `myObj`. But to create a new object with an object literal that's where you need `{}` - see the structure shown in the question or in my answer. (In your `var` statement if you replace all the `[]` with `{}` it would be correct; your `client_ip = ...` statement is already correct.)

Comment: Ok, cool. I thought for some reason that they were arrays this whole time. Oh well.. I'll edit, maybe I'll regain that -1 I just got.

Comment: Arrays are a type of object, so you can set properties on arrays with string keys as well as integer keys, but in general that is not recommended (and there's no literal syntax to make it happen) and for this purpose you definitely want a "plain" object. (I didn't downvote, so I can't undo that.)

Comment: OHHH. So that's why it's been working in the past for me? Cool, thanks.